# content permission in drupal

Tags: drupal

How do I set content permission so that specific nodes are only visible to the admin user, while other nodes of the same content type may be visible by all users.

Answer (score 2):

D6: Go to `admin/user/permissions` and make sure *access content* is unchecked for all roles.

D7: Go to `admin/people/permissions` and make sure *View published content* is unchecked for all roles other than Administrator

Comment: i want particular content type schould be not accessible , not all content in site

Comment: Then install and configure a node access module, for example http://drupal.org/project/content_access

Answer (score 2):

Best way would be to use [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) module as it provides admin/structure/types/manage/content-type/access page to manage permissions.

There you can check PER CONTENT NODE ACCESS CONTROL SETTINGS to enable content level permission for different nodes of same content type.

Now you can go to node/node-id/access page to provide permission for particular node and only assign view any content permission to admin user.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to go to the trouble of installing a new module you could just unpublish the content, then only administrators will be able to view it